# How to add subdomain with nginx and route 53?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have let's say example.com and it's running on EC2 instance with nginx and  i need to run api.example.com on the same ip of the EC2 instance as example.com i tried to create record set in route 53 for api.example.com with the same ip as example.com but api.example.com is not working. Then i tried to create new hosted zone with api.example.com and then use this NS records in my example.com hosted zone after a while api.example.com started working but it loads the same content as example.com i tried to restart nginx however i have two server block for example.com and api.example.com but it's not loading api.example.com. Please help, what am i doing wrong?